# HTML Page fit while zooming

Tags: html

I want to try to make a html page fit my screen while zooming. 
I can not specify this more or I do not know how to explain so:
Open this site http://www.airsoftgent.be/ and try zooming out, then you will see what I mean.

Help me please!!

Thank You

Comment: I don't think this relates to programming..... Does it??

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: It was just a normal question..? My friend and I are trying to make an own site, and he told me he wants something like that we do have the basics but he just want to make the page fit like in the example. 
Why do you think this does not relates to programming..?

Comment: @IcyFlame, if you want your specific site to fit while zooming, that's different than wanting all pages to fit when zooming and I think it would fit here. However, you need to do more than say "How do we do this". You need to go figure out it for yourself. Once you have an idea and have tried to implement it, then ask here.

Comment: We tried but we have no idea.. There isn't even nothing in the internet saying how to.. We don't even know how to start.. 
I'm sorry for asking.. Why can't you just help.. We were desparate and only asking, so you don't have to be angry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Situation:

I see what you want to do. Some months ago I tried to make the same thing, with succes.

You must understand I can not give you the whole code just some basic lines. Then try to implement them yourself and if there is a problem just ask.

## Solution:

I'm going to try to explain based on my own site.

#### What does *my* site contain:

First off all I have a normal HTML page with a header, main and footer. The header is not important for now.

Let's start by adding a **wrap**, place it round the *main* **and** *footer*. **Like this:**

```
    <div id="wrap"> 
      <div id="main">
        <p>Some Text Here</p>
      </div>
  
      <div id="footer">Copyright</div>
    </div>
```

**Now for the CSS file:**

We start bij adding the *body* and *html* tag:

```
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

The *body* and *html* tag must contain these items! It will not work if it doesn't!

**Then** we add the **wrap**(in CSS), make shure it contains following code, you can mess with the padding, margin and width to make it look nicer but just for now only this:

```
   #wrap{
      height: auto;
      min-height: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
```

**Explenation:**

The **min-height** is to make shure the height is always 100%, even is there is not much text.

The **position** has to be **relative**! For all the rest of the tags/classes **inside** the wrap the position has to be **absolute**! But I will explain that later on.

For the **Height: auto** we need an other explenation: since IE does not always recognizes *height: 100%*, you have to use **auto**.

**Now last but not least:** we have to add the *main* and *footer* in the CSS file:

```
    #main{
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 15px;
    }

    #footer{
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
    }
```

**Explenation:**

In the **main** you need to set the **height** to 100%, just to make shure it fills the whole wrap. And as I said set the positon to **absolute**, this has to be done just to make shure that everything stays at it's place.

Also important the **bottom** is now 15px, it refers to the height of the footer. I you want a lager footer edit this value as well or you will mess up things.

In the **footer** the same position **absolute**. And this time you have to set the **bottom** to 0px, to make shure it is place at the end of the wrap.

**So I hope you understand.** This works fine for me and does exactly what you asked.

## You will have to use padding and margin to position some things, but that is up to you, enjoy!